# Fixing Yourls Apache/htaccess config HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, plesk, yourls

In the root directory I am running wordpress and within root directory I have a directory called 'y' where I run yourls url shortening platform. Wordpress should be access through [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) while Yourls should be accessed through example.com/y/.

This was running fine until I switched from shared hosting to a VPS setup with Plesk/Apache/Nginx, DNS and SSL configured via Cloudflare.

Root/Wordpress works fines but y/yourls throws HTTP ERROR 500 with no log captured in */var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/error_log*.

Accessing https://example.com/y/ tries to load a dummy index.html I've placed there, indicating that it's not following the RewriteRule mentioned in htaccess file. (**This is a wrong assumption, as indicated by @Cbroe in the comments below**).

How can this be fixed? What can I do to debug this further?

**Root directory .htaccess as requested by wordpress**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**y directory .htaccess [as recommended in the yourls docs](https://yourls.org/docs/guide/server-configuration)**

```
# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /y/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /y/yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS
```

my apache config is located in  */var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/conf/httpd.conf* and among other things has this config two times, once for virtualhost on port 7080 and again for virtualhost on port 7081

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
                        Options -FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Indexes,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,MultiViews,ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC
</Directory>
```

Comment: _"Accessing `https://example.com/y/` tries to load a dummy index.html I've placed there, indicating that it's not following the RewriteRule mentioned in htaccess file."_ - in both your .htaccess you are rewriting only, if what was requested did not match any existing file or folder. `/y/` physically exists, so no rewriting happens. And then mod_dir takes over, and serves the DirectoryIndex document, your index.html

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my .htaccess and apache config was actually fine and the problem was in fact caused by the newer PHP 8 version that I have on the new host setup vs PHP 7 which I had on the old shared hosting setup.

This issue has been fixed by Yourls and is mentioned in this [PR](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/pull/3474). By upgrading to the latest Yourls version 1.9.2 everything went back to normal.

Comment: Although "Accessing `https://example.com/y/` tries to load a dummy index.html" would most likely still apply, as per @CBroe's comment above.

Comment: @MrWhite Fully agreed, that still applies.